# Producer/Consumer implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, concurrency

I am using Netty embedded within Grails to process and display incoming SNMP messages. Since Netty 4 doesn't come with a built-in `ChannelExecutionHandler` I had to make my own and would like some feedback on it.

```
package org.ciscotalk.common.netty;

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.channel.*;
import io.netty.channel.socket.DatagramPacket;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.ciscotalk.common.netty.exec.ChannelDecoderEvent;
import org.ciscotalk.common.snmp.SnmpMessage;
import org.ciscotalk.snmp.SnmpService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.concurrent.*;

/**
 * @author Diljot
 */
@ChannelHandler.Sharable
public class ChannelExecutionHandler
    extends CombinedChannelDuplexHandler<ChannelExecutionHandler.ChannelInboundExecutionHandler,
                         ChannelExecutionHandler.ChannelOutboundExecutionHandler>
{

    @Autowired
    @Getter @Setter
    private SnmpService snmpService;

    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private final BlockingDeque<ByteBuf> incoming = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
    //TODO private static final BlockingDeque<?> outgoing = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
    private final BlockingDeque<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();

    public ChannelExecutionHandler() {
        init(new ChannelInboundExecutionHandler(), new ChannelOutboundExecutionHandler());
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(producer);
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(consumer);
    }

    public final Runnable producer = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ChannelDecoderEvent<?> ev = nextEvent(incoming.take());
                if (ev != null) {
                    Future<?> f = executor.submit((Runnable) ev, ev);
                    futures.put(f);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    public final Runnable consumer = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Future<?> f = futures.take();
                if (f != null) {
                    Object o = f.get();
                    snmpService.pushToQueue((SnmpMessage) o);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    private <T extends SnmpMessage> ChannelDecoderEvent<T> nextEvent(ByteBuf buf) {
        return new ChannelDecoderEvent<>(buf);
    }

    public final class ChannelInboundExecutionHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
            ByteBuf buf = ((DatagramPacket) msg).content();
            buf.retain();
            incoming.put(buf);
        }

    }

    public final class ChannelOutboundExecutionHandler extends ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
            ctx.write(msg, promise);
        }

    }

}
```

---

```
package org.ciscotalk.snmp

import grails.transaction.Transactional
import org.ciscotalk.common.snmp.SnmpMessage

@Transactional
class SnmpService<T extends SnmpMessage> {

    Queue<T> incoming = new LinkedList<>()

    def pushToQueue(T obj) {
        incoming.add(obj)
    }

}
```

---

```
package org.ciscotalk.common.snmp;

/**
 * @author Diljot
 */
public interface SnmpMessage {

}
```

---

```
package org.ciscotalk.common.netty.exec;

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import org.ciscotalk.common.snmp.SnmpMessage;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

/**
 * @author Diljot
 */
public class ChannelDecoderEvent<T extends SnmpMessage> implements Callable<T> {

    private final ByteBuf buf;

    public ChannelDecoderEvent(ByteBuf buf) {
        this.buf = buf;
    }

    @Override
    public T call() throws Exception {
        // handle decoding then return encoded SnmpMessage<T>
        return null;
    }

}
```

The intended flow is:

1. `ChannelInboundExecutionHandler` receives incoming `UDP packet`, stores it as a `ByteBuf` in the `incoming queue`.
2. The `producer` thread picks up the `ByteBuf` and decodes/processes the packet by submitting a `ChannelDecoderEvent`
3. The future is stored in the `futures` queue
4. The `consumer` thread picks up the `Future<?>` and proceeds to invoke the `get()` function.
5. Upon successful recovery it passes the processed `SnmpMessage<T>` to the Grails `SnmpService` which handles persisting the data and displaying it in the Grails webapp. (This hasn't been implemented yet but that's the plan)

I would like some C&C if this model works out, or if I should handle it differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So your code/concept looks functional to me. There are some comments though... and they are a bit scattered, forgive me....

### Threads

You use the `Executors` class to create three ExecutorServices. Each of these services create threads that [are non-daemon threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#defaultThreadFactory%28%29)...

This is a problem because you will need to manually shut down all threads before you can exit your program correctly.

Using the default ThreadFactory is also a problem because the threads have horrible names. It is very convenient to name your threads so that, if there are problems, the stack-traces and java dumps are more easy to interpret.

creating a class like:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;


/**
 * Simple thread-safe ThreadFactory implementation that can be
 * customised to have a special name-base, and daemon setting.
 */
public class CustomizableThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {

    private final AtomicInteger idgen = new AtomicInteger();
    private final String basename;
    private final boolean daemon;

    /**
     * Create a new ThreadFactory with the given base-name and daemon settings.
     * Each thread created from this factory will have a unique name (basename + " - " + id)
     * @param basename the basename to use for threads from this factory
     * @param daemon whether the threads are daemon threads, or not (see Thread.setDaemon(boolean) )
     */
    public CustomizableThreadFactory(final String basename, final boolean daemon) {
        this.basename = basename;
        this.daemon = daemon;
    }

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(final Runnable torun) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(torun, String.format("%s - %d", basename, idgen.incrementAndGet()));
        thread.setDaemon(daemon);
        return thread;
    }

}
```

You can use that class anywhere you use an ExecutorService, and the threads will be much nicer to use. Consider your constructor:

> ```
> private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
> private final BlockingDeque<ByteBuf> incoming = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
> //TODO private static final BlockingDeque<?> outgoing = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
> private final BlockingDeque<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
>
> public ChannelExecutionHandler() {
>     init(new ChannelInboundExecutionHandler(), new ChannelOutboundExecutionHandler());
>     Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(producer);
>     Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(consumer);
> }
> ```

This code would be better as:

```
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(
      new CustomizedThreadFactory("SNMP Decoder" + true));
private final BlockingDeque<ByteBuf> incoming = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
private final BlockingDeque<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();

public ChannelExecutionHandler() {
    init(new ChannelInboundExecutionHandler(), new ChannelOutboundExecutionHandler());
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(
         new CustomizedThreadFactory("SNMP Producer", true)).execute(producer);
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(
         new CustomizedThreadFactory("SNMP Consumer", true)).execute(consumer);
}
```

Alright, apart from the thread daemon status and names, the rest of the thread model looks OK.....

You have a thread that queues the events in an ordered queue, then a bunch of threads that decode them in paralle, and a final thread that removes them in the same order as their insert order.

From what I can tell, this is good.

### Generics

You go part way to working with your generics, but then you get lazy, or there is an inconsistency in your code.

**Inconsistency:**

you have `Future<?> f = executor.submit((Runnable) ev, ev);` where `ev` is `ChannelDecoderEvent<?> ev = nextEvent(incoming.take());`

Now, ChannelDecoderEvent is:

> ```
> public class ChannelDecoderEvent<T extends SnmpMessage> implements Callable<T> { ...
> ```

So, you are creating a future that will result in a ChannelDecoderEvent output [(that is what the ExecutorService.submit(...) does)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable,%20T%29).

But, when you pull values from the `futures` queue with:

> ```
>             Future<?> f = futures.take();
>             if (f != null) {
>                 Object o = f.get();
>                 snmpService.pushToQueue((SnmpMessage) o);
> ```

you are casting the `o` value to be an `SnmpMessage`, but that `o` value is a `ChannelDecoderEvent`, and that is not an `SnmpMessage`, so you will get ClassCastException.

**If you did it right** ....

Your generics should be worked correctly the whole way though.

There is no need for `Future<?>`, it should be `Future<SnmpMessage>`, and instead of loading the executors as a `submit(Runnable r, T result);` you should be using the correct callable-nature of the `ChannelDecoderEvent`, and submitting as:

```
Future<? extends SnmpMessage> f = submit(ev);
```

Then, your future queue:

> ```
> private final BlockingDeque<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
> ```

should be:

```
private final BlockingDeque<Future<? extends SnmpMessage>> futures = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
```

Finally, your queue retrieval code becomes:

```
            Future<? extends SnmpMessage> f = futures.take();
            if (f != null) {
                SNMPMessage msg = f.get();
                snmpService.pushToQueue(msg);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you rolfl for your review on my code, I have looked over your suggestions and agree with them all. I will be sure to implement the changes you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

+1 to `@rolfl`. Two minor notes:

1. If your threads throws an exception they probably will be printed only to `System.out`. You might want to use an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` which logs them.
2. Consider using [`ThreadFactoryBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ThreadFactoryBuilder.html) from [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), it has a great API.

Comment: Thanks for your comment palacsint, I'll look over the Guava API as you suggested. And this code is only part-way done that's why it's missing the error output as you suggested.