# Best way to create a daemon in a JavaWeb application

Tags: java

I have a purpose for an application to run a daemon in my web application.

The application is running with Struts1 on a tomcat7 server using Java7.

This is what it does:

- Launch itself when the application is loaded
- every minutes does a task (the sysout in the code)
- when the application stops, it stops the timer and let the task 10 sec max to finish its process if needed

In the web.xml file i have these lines to launch the process:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.toto.tata.applicationlayer.BiuDeamon</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And here is the code:

```
package com.toto.tata.applicationlayer;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class BiuDeamon implements ServletContextListener {
    private static boolean isDaemonWorking = false;
    private static Timer timer;
    private static TimerTask timerTask;

    static {
        timerTask = new TimerTask(){
            public void run() {
                if (!isDaemonWorking) {
                    try {
                        isDaemonWorking = true;

                        System.out.println("I RUN");

                        isDaemonWorking = false;
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public BiuDeamon() {
        super();
    }

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent a_event) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, new Date(), 60000);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent a_event) {
        // we stop the timer
        timer.cancel();
        // we let the timertask 10 sec to stop its processing
        int i=0;
        for (; i<10; i++) {
            if (isDaemonWorking) {
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        // we kill it if needed
        if (i==10)
            timerTask.cancel();
    }
}
```

I know my code is working because I have tested it, but I wonder if there is a better way to achieve what I want.

Any comments / examples will be appreciated :)

Comment: Just a quick idea: I would use `shutdown()` instead of the *first* `shutdownNow()`.

Comment: that didn't change a thing.

Comment: Please see [this meta post on how to have a successful iterative code review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41/iterative-code-reviews-how-can-they-happen-successfully). I have rolled-back your update.

Comment: @rolfl So basicaly you tell me to make another question to my edit? As i ask a question, I understand it, but I put the code also to show people how my code has changed according to the choosen response and see how it can be implemented. I know my second question would have a better place on stackoverflow, I'll get there for this then :)

Comment: @Damounet - it's not about stopping you from showing your revised code, it is about making the answers keep making sense, and allowing other people to make sensible answers in the future about other aspects of your code.

Comment: Ok I'll edit this properly according to [this answer](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/538/49708)

Comment: I posted the wrong link, I apologise. Code Review is evolving, and I searched for the wrong thing. This is the right link: [For an iterative review, is it okay to edit my own question to include revised code?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Using a `ServletContextListener` is a good solution, I would use the same.
2. I would consider using a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) here ([`Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool%28int%29)). It has some advantages:

   - It has a `scheduleWithFixedDelay` method as well as `scheduleAtFixedRate`. Using one of these describes what's the developer's purpose. Currently its not completely obvious or explicit.
   - It supports `shutdown` and `awaitTermination`. `awaitTermination` returns immediately when your task finishes, no need to wait complete seconds.
   - `awaitTermination` returns `false` on timeout when you can call `shutdownNow` which interrupts the thread of the task.
   - It does not need manual and error-prone synchronization (see the next point).
   - [`newScheduledThreadPool` can get a `ThreadFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool%28int,%20java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory%29). You can set a `UncaughtExceptionHandler` to handle uncatched exceptions with that factory. ([See also this answer too](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/43154/7076).)
3. Usage of `isDaemonWorking` is not thread-safe. It is used by the timer's thread (inside the `TimerTask.run` method) as well as the `ServletContextListener`. Without any synchronization you risk that threads will not see each other's modification.

   > [...] synchronization has no effect unless both read and write operations are synchronized.

   From *Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 66: Synchronize access to shared mutable data*.
4. You could invert the `if` condition here:

   > ```
   > for (; i<10; i++) {
   >     if (isDaemonWorking) {
   >         try {
   >             TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
   >         } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
   >             Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   >         }
   >     } else {
   >         break;
   >     }
   > }
   > ```

   It would [keep the code flatten](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/):

   ```
   for (; i < 10; i++) {
       if (!isDaemonWorking) {
           break;
       }
       try {
           TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
       } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
           Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
       }
   }
   ```
5. I guess if you put the `isDaemonWorking = false` into a `finally` block:

   ```
   try {
       isDaemonWorking = true;
       System.out.println("I RUN");
   } catch (Throwable e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
       isDaemonWorking = false;
   }
   ```

   then you could replace

   > ```
   > if (i == 10)
   >     timerTask.cancel();
   > ```

   with

   ```
   if (isDaemonWorking) {
       timerTask.cancel();
   }
   ```

   and use an usual `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` loop too.
6. I would not think that initialization of `TimerTask` should be in a static block. The `timer` and `isDaemonWorking` also could be instance fields. I think (and I would expect that) the servlet container calls `contextDestroyed` on the same instance than `contextInitialized`.
7. Variable names in Java usually `camelCase`, so `a_event` should be `aEvent` or just `event` here:

   > ```
   > public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent a_event) {
   > ```
8. I guess you have a typo here: `BiuDeamon` (it should be `BuiDaemon`).

Comment: I thought it was a very big issue that the current variables are static. The `timer` for example is shared over all `BiuDaemon` instances, is that not calling for disaster? I'm not aware of the workings of a `ServletContextListener` though.

Comment: Secondly, should a `scheduleAtFixedRate` always be prepared over a `Timer` with a `TimerTask`? Especially since Java 8 requires you to write an anonymous inner class for the `TimerTask`?

Comment: @skiwi: Good point. Containers create only one instance for `ServletContextListener`s (if you have only one `listener` tag), so it probably does not cause any problem but it smells and error-prone.

Comment: @skiwi: `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate` needs a `Runnable` instance and calls the `run` method of the same instance.

Comment: Great help @palacsint ! I have done some researchs and update my code in the original post. Comments are welcome :)